# Is this the right use-case for on demand ISR in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, serverless, vercel

So I am building an app that lets you search for a word and gives you the word in other languages. A clone to [this site](https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/)

I just tried Next.js On Demand ISR feature and I did that because fetching from the client using API routes was **too slow** in my app.

I also thought of generating static pages but that would cause **hundreds of thousands** of static pages.

Here's how my code looks like now:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  console.log("[Next.js] Running getStaticPaths for word page");
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { word: "1" } }, { params: { word: "2" } }],
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: GetStaticPropsContext) {
  const db = await getContainer();

  const { resources } = await db.items
    .query(
      `SELECT c.language, c.Translation, c.id FROM c WHERE c.PrimaryWord='${params?.word}'`
    )
    .fetchAll();

  return {
    props: {
      resources,
    },
  };
}
```

I saw a difference in the performance using this approach instead of normal API routes and client-side fetching that took so long.

But I don't know if this is the right use-case of on-demand ISR and if this is the right approach to it or not.

Comment: How exactly are you using [on-demand ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation) here? Isn't this just incremental static generation (without the on-demand/re-generation part) - see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking? If that's what your question is about, then yes, this is a valid use case for ISG. Keep in mind that you're still generating the pages statically, it just happens to be when the first request for it comes through, rather than at build time.

Comment: Actually I am not regenerating the pages here. But I am kind of following the same pattern in the project Lee Rob built for the on demand ISR demo